# Vestacp service stopped

Tags: nginx, service, restart

I have VestaCp and nginx on my server and  want to restart my service when its stopped.

Example sometimes nginx stop and need to restart manually.So in this time my websites not accessible.I have Centos 7.1.

Comment: Please provide any approach you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Monit software. It is free and you'll find a lot of examples over the internet.

Idk if Centos has that package at `yum install monit`, for sure it is on the Debian repos.

A basic monitor for a web service that is running inside a webserver should use http check at desired port, ie 80 front nginx or 8080 apache2 reverse_proxy.

Example at [git examples](https://gist.github.com/1415908):

```
# nginx
check process nginx with pidfile /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
stop  program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80 then restart
if cpu is greater than 40% for 2 cycles then alert
if cpu > 60% for 5 cycles then restart 
if 10 restarts within 10 cycles then timeout
```

Minimum nginx and alert configuration:

```
# email alerts
set mailserver localhost
set mail-format { from: monit@localhost OR you@your-domain.com }
set alert your-email@your-domain.com
# nginx
check process nginx with pidfile /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/nginx start"
stop  program = "/etc/init.d/nginx stop"
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80 then restart
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80 then alert
```

What it does is self explanatory.

Usually you should put individual files for each service you monitor, and keep them clean. Also, example service are provider, and you can enable them just putting them on the correct folder.

A good documentation with quick examples is at [that link](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-MONITORING-MODE)

I use it and it is really cool. As you see you can run many programs in case of almos any event trigger. You can watch pids, ports and many other things.

You ask about nginx, but of course you can watch at vesta service too. Vesta admin panel runs in another nginx process that is not handled by the nginx service installed, because this one is used to nginx proxy at hosting.

So, there are 2 nginx processes and you'll watch both, 8083 and 80 (and 443 for ssl)

I got some problems in the past monitoring apache2 by the pid, so http check is better at all. If does listen is running.

Best of luck.